# Difference between fflush(stdin) and flushstdin()

Tags: c, stdin, fflush

What is the difference between using `fflush(stdin)`
and `flushstdin()`? The only difference I know is that I need to write that void stuff before using `flushstdin()`, but I don't know why.

```
void flushstdin()
{
    int c;
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF); 
}
int main () {
    float a, b, c;
    float s=0, ar1=0, ar2=0;
    printf("Inform value of side A");
    while(scanf("%f",&a) != 1 || a <= 0){ 
        printf("Invalid value.\n");
        flushstdin();
    }
}
```

and

```
int main(){
    float a,b,c,s=0;
    printf("Inform value of side A.");
    while(scanf("%f",&a) != 1 || a<=0){
        printf("Invalid value.\n");
        fflush(stdin);
    }
}
```

I'm a beginner! Which code is the best? Or they are equal?

Comment: What do you mean by *I need to write that void stuff before using flushstdin()*?

Comment: @RSahu this:

void flushstdin()
{
    int c;
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);

Comment: Ask the person who told you to "write that void stuff". You also should tell her that this "void stuff" is a _function_ and that one does not "write" it (in context of files "to write something" has certain semantics), but _define_ (and here also _declare_) and lateron _call_. He really should get the terms right, so others will actually understand what you're talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both versions have problems.

As was already extensively documented, `fflush(stdin)` has undefined behaviour per the C Standard. The alternative using the `flushstdin()` function is not much better.  I suggest reading standard input one line at a time and parsing that with `sscanf()`, all in a utility function that you can use as needed:

```
int readfloat(const char *prompt, float *val) {
    char buf[128];
    for (;;) {
        if (prompt) 
            fputs(prompt, stdout);
        if (!fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin)) {
            printf("Premature end of file\n");
            return 1;
        }
        if (sscanf(buf, "%f", val) == 1 && *val > 0)
            return 0;
        printf("Invalid value.\n");
    }
}

int main(void) {
    float a, b, c, s = 0;
    if (readfloat("Enter value of side A: ", &a))
        return 1;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Difference is that `flushstdin` is user defined and the only way in standard C to flush `stdin`.
`fflush` is a standard library function. `fflush(stdin);` will invoke undefined behavior.

[c- faq: 12.26a](http://www.c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush.html):

> **`fflush` is defined only for output streams**. Since its definition of "flush" is to complete the writing of buffered characters (not to discard them), discarding unread input would not be an analogous meaning for `fflush` on input streams.

[c-faq: 12.26b](http://www.c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush2.html):

> There is no standard way to discard unread characters from a stdio input stream. **Some vendors do implement `fflush` so that `fflush(stdin)` discards unread characters, although portable programs cannot depend on this**. (Some versions of the `stdio` library implement `fpurge` or `fabort` calls which do the same thing, but these aren't standard, either.) Note, too, that flushing `stdio` input buffers is not necessarily sufficient: unread characters can also accumulate in other, OS-level input buffers. If you're trying to actively discard input (perhaps in anticipation of issuing an unexpected prompt to confirm a destructive action, for which an accidentally-typed "y" could be disastrous), you'll have to use a system-specific technique to detect the presence of typed-ahead input; see questions 19.1 and 19.2. Keep in mind that users can become frustrated if you discard input that happened to be typed too quickly.

Comment: So I should not use fflush(stdin)??

Comment: @RafaelMoura It is no longer a portable program.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY what do you mean ? =(

Comment: @RafaelMoura There is no guarantee that the same behavior in others of the environment.

Comment: Even where `fflush(stdin)` works, it "flushes" `stdin` in a different sense than the OP's `flushstdin` function. See my answer.

Comment: Note that some systems *do* define a behavior for `fflush( stdin )` that does what most people expect; that is, clear all data from the input stream.  Apparently that was easier than convincing N-thousand programmers to *not do that*.  However, that behavior should not be relied upon in general, and you should not use `fflush( stdin )` in your code.

Comment: @JohnBode; I thought readers will go read the c-faq I linked for suggested reading. Now, added that too in my answer which include your point.

Answer (score 2):

They are quite different. They can both "flush" input, but in different senses of that word.

`fflush` is a standard C function. Its behavior on input streams such as `stdin` is *undefined* -- meaning that the C standard does not define its behavior.

Some systems do define the behavior of `fflush` on an input stream. For example on Linux:

> For input streams, `fflush()` discards any buffered data that has been
>   fetched from the underlying file, but has not been consumed by the
>   application.

You can rely on `fflush(stdin)` to behave in accordance with this description *if* your program runs on a Linux-based system, or on another system that documents the same behavior. Your program's behavior will not be portable; on other systems, it might behave in arbitrarily bad ways. (Most likely if `fflush(stdin)` doesn't work, it will do nothing other than returning an error indication, but that's not guaranteed.)

Your own `flushstdin` function does something different from the Linux behavior of `fflush(stdin)`. It reads and discards all input functions up to the first newline or until `EOF` (which is triggered either by end-of-file or by an error). It does this regardless of whether that input is buffered or not.

For example, suppose you type the chacters `hello` (without a newline), then your program calls `fflush(stdin)`, *and then* you enter a newline.

`fflush(stdin)`, given the Linux documented behavior, will discard the `hello` and return immediately, leaving the newline to be read by a later call. It "flushes" `stdin` in the sense that it discards all pending input, regardless of what it is.

Your `flushstdin()` function will read and discard the `hello` and then wait until you type <kbd>Enter</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd>), and then read and discard that. It reads and discards all input up to a newline or EOF, regardless of whether it was pending at the time of the call.

And again, the behavior of `fflush(stdin)` is not defined by the C standard, so using it makes your program non-portable (and your compiler will not necessarily warn you about that).

Incidentally, "that void stuff" is the *definition* of the `flushstdin` function. It's not needed for `fflush` because that's a standard C library function that's already defined for you.

Comment: How could one type characters without newline?

Comment: @haccks: It depends if the terminal is in cooked or raw mode, and if `stdin` is line buffered or not...

Comment: @haccks: By typing some characters and not typing a newline.

Comment: @KeithThompson; Lol. Of course but how program will call `fflush(stdin)` without pressing Enter key?

Comment: @haccks: I think chqrlie's comment is correct. And even if `stdin` is line-buffered, the characters are still *buffered* and should be discarded by `fflush(stdin)` if it behaves as the Linux man page describes it.

Comment: @haccks: Or maybe not. Experiment shows that line-buffered characters are not flushed by `fflush(stdin)` on Linux. In fact I don't see `fflush(stdin)` having any effect at all; perhaps I'm doing something wrong. I have no plans to use it in real code, so perhaps I just won't worry about it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I was a bit lost.